# Parsing information from IMAP body html

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to IMAP and I'm able to extract an email body in html form. But I'm trying to get the following link below. How can I do this?

In the email content it has divs everywhere and the url i need to get has the link below surrounded by div.

I'm trying to get https://webpage.testing.com/new_setup as a string.

I've used the code below but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
    String urlReg = "^<div>https";

    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(urlReg);
    Matcher mtch = regex.matcher(body);

    while(mtch.find()){
        System.out.println(mtch.group(1));
    }
```

Am I approaching this right? How do i grab a url from an email content?

Comment: Can you write here a subset of the text where you intent to do the match? Or perhaps a link to the webpage

Comment: Don't attempt to parse with regular expressions. It is a contradiction in terms. Use an HTML parser.  IMAP has exactly nothing to do with it.

Comment: There are seveal good HTML parsers; what you want is [one of the examples for jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links).

Comment: @arnt worked like a charm. I used jsoup to parse the html body and then found the div pertaining to the URL. Then all i had to do was extract the actual url. Thanks!